# Stegano: embedding the same secret in multiple images returns wrong result

Tags: python, steganography

I've been trying to do steganography on multiple images from one directory and save them in another using the [Stegano](https://stegano.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#) module.

I've came up with the code:

```
from stegano import slsb
import os, sys

APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
path = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'current_folder/')
dirs = os.listdir( path )
new_path = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'new_folder/')
dirs2 = os.listdir( new_path )

def stegogal():
    for item in dirs:
        if os.path.isfile(path+item):
            sw = "secretword"
            f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item+'.png')
            secret = slsb.hide(f, sw)
            f, e = os.path.splitext(new_path+item+'.png')
            secret.save(f + '_G.png')

stegogal()
```

However, the secret world in nearly all the images (2 out of 3) will be messed up in some way. For example it will hide `"secretworg"` instead of `"secretword"`.

Can someone explain to me what seems to be the problem and perhaps show some better way to do it?

Comment: just update stegano module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 2 : bug fixed, commit release dont use the solution bellow any more

**Edit : new version with bug fix to come**

lenght bug

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from stegano import slsb
import os, sys

APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
path = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'current_folder/')
dirs = os.listdir( path )
new_path = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'new_folder/')
dirs2 = os.listdir( new_path )

def stegogal():
    for item in dirs:
        if os.path.isfile(path+item):
            sw = ur"secretword" + ur" " 
            f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item+'.png')
            secret = slsb.hide(f, sw)
            f, e = os.path.splitext(new_path+item+'.png')
            secret.save(f + '_G.png')

stegogal()
print(slsb.reveal("secret.png")[:-1])
```

Comment: No, doesn't work for me. Still, the same thing happens.

Comment: No, the same problem happens(

Comment: i have the same error as yours if i dont use raw string.

Comment: What's your python version ?

Comment: My python version is 2.7.11

Comment: you're right there a lenght bug, depending on secret word's lenght, i posted you a quick and ugly fix

Comment: keep it, it does start every script you have in python2

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in embedding the secret. The program encodes the length of the message so it knows how many bits to read for extraction. Internally, your message becomes

```
message = str(len(message)) + ":" + message
```

which, in your case, is 104 bits. Since this is not divisible by 3, the bug kicks in here

```
if index + 3 <= len(message_bits):
```

and you only embed the first 102 bits. For the extraction the program will read sufficient bits to reconstruct the message, but the last 2 bits will be at the mercy of whatever pixel values your original image has (you may even not notice a problem by coincidence).

```
>>> '{:08b}'.format(ord('d'))
'01100100'
>>> '{:08b}'.format(ord('g'))
'01100111'
>>>
```

While the quick hack posted by a different answer addresses the problem, it does so by transferring it somewhere else where it can be ignored. It'd be more convenient (and correct) to fix the source code so you can conveniently import the correct function without relying on any wrapper patches.

Either pad `message_bits` with the necessary number of 0s to make its length divisible by 3 (they will be discarded after the extraction),

```
message_bits = "".join(tools.a2bits_list(message))
message_bits += '0' * ((3 - (len(message_bits) % 3)) % 3)
```

or change the embedding routine to not skip any bits when you have fewer than 3 left.

```
for row in range(height):
    for col in range(width):
        if index + 3 <= len(message_bits):
            (r, g, b) = img.getpixel((col, row))

            r = tools.setlsb(r, message_bits[index])
            g = tools.setlsb(g, message_bits[index+1])
            b = tools.setlsb(b, message_bits[index+2])

            encoded.putpixel((col, row), (r, g , b))
            index += 3
        elif index < len(message_bits):
            # More bits left, but not enough to embed in r, g and b.
            (r, g, b) = img.getpixel((col, row))

            r = tools.setlsb(r, message_bits[index])
            index += 1
            if index < len(message_bits):
                g = tools.setlsb(g, message_bits[index])
                index += 1

            encoded.putpixel((col, row), (r, g , b))
        else:
            # Embedding is done, no point in iterating over more pixels
            return encoded
return encoded
```

Mind you, the same bug exists in the `slsbset` module.

Comment: Since there are 4 possible letters (d, e, f and g), for a sufficiently large sample of images you'd expect to get the wrong result 3 out of 4 times. However, this assumes neither the LSBs of the red and green colour planes are correlated, nor are there any correlations between the images themselves.

Comment: plus one, Thanks for the explanation

Comment: i tested, the quick dirty fix works for every lenght. the perfect solution is to fix bug.

Comment: @LonGdueZBOO It works because it transfers that problem to the padded character, which is later discared. Admitedly, I didn't see that you do discard it and I assumed it was up to the user to pad the message with the correct number of characters. Still, it's a sweep-under-the-carpet solution. :)

Comment: no in fact you're totatlly right, i tested, there is a bug depending on pixel componant.

Comment: (r, g, b) = img.getpixel((col, row))
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Comment: @LonGdueZBOO I think the problem here is that you attempted to load a grayscale image, which has only one colour component. However, that's a design issue of the algorithm, which isn't related to the relevant bug here. You can see whether `img.mode` returns `'RGB'`. You can convert it to RGB with `img = img.convert('RGB')`.